# Sentence translation " ... videat, annon implacabilem Deum quoque sit experturus"

Tags: translation-check, latin-to-english-translation, sentence-translation

In De differentiis verborum, [under the entry of *Clemens*](https://books.google.com/books?id=9i6Ogx8aCJIC&pg=PA115&dq=%22sed+implacidus%22&hl=iw&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwi198D1gKDqAhUDLewKHdYABTQQ6AEwAHoECAUQAg#v=onepage&q=%22sed%20implacidus%22&f=false), Pompa contrasts that word with *placidus*, and right afterwards writes:

> Sed *implacidus*, qui nullo placamine ad placabilitatem promovetur, ut se placatum ostendat, videat, annon implacabilem Deum quoque sit experturus.

What I understood thus far:

> But the *implacidus*, without any means of appeasing him (to be pushed by them towards calmness), in order that he might display himself placid. Let him see [?].

I have my doubts also of my interpretation of the first part, but it is in the last section I have greater difficulty with. It seem that I can't reconcile the "(quoque) sit experturus" with the sentence. I was thinking maybe:

> Let him see, and find out, doesn't it so, God [also] not able to be pleased.

But in this interpretation, I can't make sense of the word order. And if "sit experturus" related to Deum, shouldn't it be in indirect speech taking the accusative as "implacabilem Deum"?

---

As as side note, I would like to ask if we can connect the "ut se ..."  with "videat ..." [ in order to x, do y], but as far as I saw, *ut* in that sense always comes after the clause?

---

**Edit**: Thanks for the helpful answers.Reading them, I would like to suggest my own which is kind of merge between the two and has softer and less harsh tone, which I prefer:

> But the *implacidus*, who by no [regular] means of appeasing is moved
> to placability, Let him consider, in order that he shows himself
> placid, whether he will not find God to be implacable as well.

Answer (score 8):

I agree  with Sebastian Koppehel and the other commenters regarding most of their general comments, but I think that everyone may be overlooking the possibility that the *ut* clause might be taken as a result clause subordinated to the *qui* clause.  Then *annon* can be read as introducing an indirect question subordinated to videat.  A somewhat literal translation of what I am proposing would run along these lines:

> But let the *implacidus*, who by no token of appeasment is moved to placability such that he shows himself placated, see whether he does not also find God to be implacable.

Answer (score 4):

Yes, we can connect the *ut* to the *videat*, and no, the *ut* does not always come second.

Rule number one of Latin: **The words can be in any order.**

*Videre ut* means “take care that, make sure that, see to it that.” The *implacidus* must also be the subject of *sit experturus*, as *Deum*, in the accusative, cannot be the subject (instead must be the object). Let's look up [*experiri*](http://www.perseus.tufts.edu/hopper/text?doc=Perseus%3Atext%3A1999.04.0059%3Aentry%3Dexperior), it can mean “find out,” but the more literal meaning is “to try, prove, put to the test.” In the case of “trying God,” we might also say “tempt.”

**Edit:** As pointed out by TKR in the comments, a more likely interpretation is *to find, experience something or someone to be something*. Unless I am overlooking it, this meaning is barely touched upon in Lewis & Short, but [Georges (1913)](http://www.zeno.org/Georges-1913/A/experior?hl=experior) actually mentions it explicitly (II, 1, α under „u. m. dopp. Acc“) and gives a number of nice examples like *aliquem fortem inimicum experiri*.

So we get:

> But the fierce (implacidus) […] should take care that he shows himself peaceful (placatus), or else he will find God to be implacable too.

(As noted in the comment, *annon* seems a little out of place. Apparently, *annon* can sometimes be found where one would expect *an*; for example my dictionary insists one can say: *utrum mentitus es annon verum dixisti*.)

Comment: Thanks for the educating answer! I have it now. yet the *annon* still seems to me out of place. wouldn't *an* (without the non), be better as the meaning of "or rather"?

Comment: I'm guessing *experiri* here has the meaning of "experience, find", i.e. the implacable person will find God too to be implacable.

Comment: @TKR Excellent point, now that you point it out it seems the better interpretation to me as well.

Comment: According to [L&S](http://www.perseus.tufts.edu/hopper/text?doc=Perseus:text:1999.04.0059:entry=an1) , in C: "Sometimes the opinion of the speaker or the probability inclines to the second interrogative clause (cf. infra, II. E.). and this is made emphatic, as a corrective of the former, or rather, or on the contrary" . So maybe you can use *annon* in the sense of *an*, but where the speaker is *not* inclined to the second, but to the first clause. it fits your example indeed, where the speaker does not seem to think that his friend was speaking the truth.